# Codeigniter hook for allowed characters of input

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

you know by default codeigniter does not allow all types of characters to be passed to the input `$_POST/$_GET`

Now, I want to write a hook to handle this, to allow more characters. But I do not what hook point to use. Does anyone know how to write such hook? thanks.

Here is the codeIgniter default function to handle input allowed chars.

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
        {
            exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');

        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
        {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Codeigniter doesn't mess with your get/post unless you tell it to, it just contains an allowed characters list for URI segments which is a totally different thing. so if you're really using get/post you don't have to do anything special to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow more charaters in url you just have to edit the URI allowed chars list that you find into `config/config.php`

Here you are :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9%.:_\-#';
```

Then whenever you want to extend a Library such as Input library , you must create a new library called `class MY_Input extends CI_Input{ }`

[here everything you need to know](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) ;)